# Python: how to assign multiple values to one key

Tags: python, json, api, data-extraction

I extract data using API and retrieve a list of servers and backups. Some servers have more than one backup. This is how I get list of all servers with backaup IDs.

```
bkplist = requests.get('https://heee.com/1.2/storage/backup')
bkplist_json = bkplist.json()
backup_list = bkplist.json()
backupl = backup_list['storages']['storage']
```

Json looks like this:

```
{
   "storages": {
      "storage": [
         {
            "access": "",
            "created": "",
            "license": ,
            "origin": "01165",
            "size": ,
            "state": "",
            "title": "",
            "type": "backup",
            "uuid": "01019",
            "zone": ""
         },
```

Firstly I create a dictionary to store this data:

```
backup = {}
for u in backup_list['storages']['storage']:
    srvuuidorg = u['origin']
    backup_uuid = u['uuid']
    backup[srvuuidorg] = backup_uuid
```

But then I find out there is more than one value for every server. As dictionary can have just one value assigned to one key I wanted to use some hybrid of list and dictionary, but I just can't figure it out how to do this with this example.

Servers are nested in **storages**->**storage** and I need to assign a couple of **uuid** which is backup ID to one **origin** which is server ID.

I know about **collections** module and with a simple example it is quite understandable, but I have a problem how to use this in my example with extracting data through API.

How extract **origin** and assign to this key other values stored in json **uuid**?

What's more it is a massive amount of data so I cannot add every value manually.

Comment: How about list of dictionaries?`{key: [valueDict1,valueDict2]}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

backup = defaultdict(list)
for u in backup_list['storages']['storage']: 
    srvuuidorg = u['origin'] 
    backup_uuid = u['uuid'] 
    backup[srvuuidorg].append(backup_uuid)
```

Note that you can simplify your loop like this.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

backup = defaultdict(list)
for u in backup_list['storages']['storage']:
    backup[u['origin']].append(u['uuid'])
```

But this may be considering as less readable.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You could store `uuid` list for `origin` key.

I sugget the following 2 ways:

1. Creating empty `list` for first accessing `origin`, and then appending to it:

```py
backup = {}
for u in backup_list['storages']['storage']:
    srvuuidorg = u['origin']
    backup_uuid = u['uuid']
    if not backup.get(srvuuidorg):
        backup[srvuuidorg] = []
    backup[srvuuidorg].append(backup_uuid)
```

2. Using `defaultdict` collection, which basically does the same for you under the hood:

```py
from collections import defaultdict


backup = defaultdict(list)
for u in backup_list['storages']['storage']:
    srvuuidorg = u['origin']
    backup_uuid = u['uuid']
    backup[srvuuidorg].append(backup_uuid)
```

It seems to me that the last way is more elegant.
If you need to store `uuid` unique list you should use the saem approach with `set` instead of `list`.

Answer (score 1):

A json allows to contain an array in a key:

```
var= {
  "array": [
    {"id": 1, "value": "one"},
    {"id": 2, "value": "two"},
    {"id": 3, "value": "three"}
  ]
}

print var
{'array': [{'id': 1, 'value': 'one'}, {'id': 2, 'value': 'two'}, {'id': 3, 'value': 'three'}]}

var["array"].append({"id": 4, "value": "new"})

print var

{'array': [{'id': 1, 'value': 'one'}, {'id': 2, 'value': 'two'}, {'id': 3, 'value': 'three'}, {'id': 4, 'value': 'new'}]}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a massive amount of data and I cannot assign everything manually. These values (uuid) should be added automatically to key (origin) through iteration and this is problematic for me.

Comment: Can you generate uuid randomly and assign them automatically via a loop?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list for multiple values.

```
dict = {"Greetings": ["hello", "hi"]}
```